# How to save image in custom location programatically in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiimage

I need to save image in different location in my ipod device IOS. By default it saves in Camera roll. I need to save in some other location. Whether the below code works? 
If works anyone please convert it into c#

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest *newAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
        newAssetRequest.creationDate = time;
        newAssetRequest.location = location;

        PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholderAsset = newAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *addAssetRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:WHICH_ASSET_COLLECTION];
        addAssetRequest addAssets:@[placeholderAsset];

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %d", success);
    }];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can save the image in the document directory of the app. Look at this link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/save_photo_to_app_directory/

Comment: How to check document directory in ipod? There's a default photos album in which camera roll folder is located.

Comment: Thanka a lot @Gagan_iOS it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String, Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to save an image to a path you put as parameter:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(PATH_TO_LOCATION, byteArray);
```

Comment: How to get path location in IOS.I dont want to save image in camera roll.How to get path of some other location in iphone?